# Freebase not returning all available values

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to extract the link to the NYTimes Topic page (among the topic_equivalent_webpage values) for Barack Obama from Freebase, but my query doesn't return any results, although it's on the webpage (http://www.freebase.com/m/02mjmr). This is my query:

```
[{
 "id": "/en/barack_obama",
 "type": "/common/topic",
 "topic_equivalent_webpage": {
   "value": null,
   "value~=": "*nytimes*"
 }
}]
```

I've also tried extracting all of the topic_equivalent_webpage values instead, using this query:

```
[{
"id": "/en/barack_obama",
"type": "/common/topic",
"topic_equivalent_webpage": []
}]
```

For some reason it only returns one of the values (http://www.worldcat.org/wcidentities/lccn-n94-112934).

Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: All Freebase APIs are going away in a few months.

You have three choices:

1. Download the RDF dump and filter it.  This is most appropriate for a large-scale download instead of using the API.  For the property name and decoding process, see #3.
2. Use the Topic API i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/barack_obama?filter=/common/topic/topic_equivalent_webpage
3. [Query](https://www.freebase.com/query?lang=%2Flang%2Fen&q=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%2Fen%2Fbarack_obama%22%2C%22key%22%3A%5B%7B%22namespace%22%3A%22%2Fsource%2Fnytimes%22%2C%22value%22%3Anull%7D%5D%7D%5D) MQL for the keys in the namespace that you want (ie the NY Times namespace)

`[{
      "id": "/en/barack_obama",
      "key": [{
        "namespace": "/source/nytimes",
        "value": null
      }]
    }]`

Normally the result is an identifier that gets substituted into a URI template, but in the NYT case it's basically a full URI path that just gets appended to http://nytimes.com/

The key value (e.g. `top$002Freference$002Ftimestopics$002Fpeople$002Fo$002Fbarack_obama`) will be MQL key encoded, so they'll need to be decoded, but in this case you can probably cheat and replace all "$002F" substrings with "/".  If any other characters are encoded, just replace $dddd with the character that has that Unicode code point.